# React Native: How to use Java code to fetch data via React Native async storage

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

- Is it possible to fetch data from React Native Async-Storage through the Android-Java code?
- If it is possible then, how can I use Android-Java code to fetch Async-Storage data (id etcs).

My data structure for RN Async Storage are: (id, fname, lname, isactive)

**What I want to do:**

I want to use the Java code for Android to connect with RN Async Storage and get the values of the data. eg: id, fname, lname .. etcs.

Comment: any update about this?

Comment: I'm looking for this as well. I'm shocked how limited RNCs' documentation is.... There is absolutely no info about anything.

Comment: Check out this answer --> [How to Read AsyncStorage on Android Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151030/how-to-read-asyncstorage-on-android-correctly)