# How to Read AsyncStorage on Android Correctly

Tags: android, react-native, redux, asyncstorage, redux-persist

It seems that it's possible access the `AsyncStorage` from Android (native); but I still struggling to make this work.

In my React Native application, I have something like:

**Store**

```
const config = {
  ...
}

export const reducers = {
  ...
  user: user
}


let rootReducer = combineReducers(reducers)
let reducer = persistReducer(config, rootReducer)
```

**User Reducer**

```
export class Actions {
    ...
}

const initialState = {
      first_name: : null,
      last_name: : null,
      email: null,
      addresses: [
          { ... }
      ]
    }
  }
}

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
  }
}
```

**Getting the User from store**

```
const user = store.getState().user
console.log(user.first_name) // Steve
...
```

---

Now the issue starts when I try to get the same user from Android, of all my frustrated attempts this is what I have:

```
try {
    readableDatabase = ReactDatabaseSupplier.getInstance(getReactApplicationContext()).getReadableDatabase();
    catalystLocalStorage = readableDatabase.query("catalystLocalStorage", new String[]{"value"}, "key = ?", new String[] { "full_name" }, null, null, null);
    String[] names = catalystLocalStorage.getColumnNames();
    if (catalystLocalStorage.moveToFirst()) {
        final String value = catalystLocalStorage.getString(catalystLocalStorage.getColumnIndex("value"));
        Log.d(TAG, value);
    }
} finally {
    if (catalystLocalStorage != null) {
        catalystLocalStorage.close();
    }

    if (readableDatabase != null) {
        readableDatabase.close();
    }
}
```

Since the User it's an object, I don't know if this is the right way to get the `'first_name'`, I tried get `'user'` but didn't worked.

I'm starting to think that I should use [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) where I would know my data structure, but I don't know if I would be able to access that database on Android.

PS: I want access `AsyncStorage` not `SharedPreferences`

---

**Lib Versions**

```
react-native: 0.48.4
redux: 3.7.2
redux-persist: 5.4.0
```

**Some questions that didn't work**

- [Access AsyncStorage from native code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514952/access-asyncstorage-from-native-code)
- [Can I access data stored in React Native's AsyncStorage from java layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164887/can-i-access-data-stored-in-react-natives-asyncstorage-from-java-layer/47551790#47551790)
- [React Native: How to use Java code to fetch data via React Native async storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635641/react-native-how-to-use-java-code-to-fetch-data-via-react-native-async-storage)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AsyncStorage` it's an unique JSON Object and instead I was expecting many rows of `key` and `value`; That's why I was getting null.

So first I continue with the query

```
catalystLocalStorage = readableDatabase.query("catalystLocalStorage", new String[]{"key", "value"}, null, null, null, null, null);
```

then I check to avoid null pointer

```
if (catalystLocalStorage.moveToFirst()) {
```

then I do the fetch

```
do {
    // JSONObject will ask for try catch
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(catalystLocalStorage.getString(catalystLocalStorage.getColumnIndex("value")));
} while(catalystLocalStorage.moveToNext());
```

I'm sure that may have better ways to do this, but right know I'm fine with that.

If you have better ideas please leave your thought.

**UPDATE**

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.modules.storage.ReactDatabaseSupplier;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AsyncStorage {

    public static String TAG = "RNAsyncStorage";
    public ReactApplicationContext context;
    public ArrayList<JSONObject> collection;
    public JSONObject data;
    public JSONObject user;

    Cursor catalystLocalStorage = null;
    SQLiteDatabase readableDatabase = null;

    public AsyncStorage (ReactApplicationContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.collection = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
        this.fetch();
        this.setUser();
    }

    public void fetch() {
        try {
            readableDatabase = ReactDatabaseSupplier.getInstance(context).getReadableDatabase();
            catalystLocalStorage = readableDatabase.query("catalystLocalStorage", new String[]{"key", "value"}, null, null, null, null, null);

            if (catalystLocalStorage.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    try {
                        // one row with all AsyncStorage: { "user": { ... }, ... }
                        String json = catalystLocalStorage.getString(catalystLocalStorage.getColumnIndex("value"));
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);

                        String user = obj.getString("user");

                        JSONObject res = new JSONObject();
                        res.put("user", new JSONObject(user));

                        collection.add(res);
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        // do something
                    }
                } while(catalystLocalStorage.moveToNext());
            }
        } finally {
            if (catalystLocalStorage != null) {
                catalystLocalStorage.close();
            }

            if (readableDatabase != null) {
                readableDatabase.close();
            }

            data = this.collection.get(0);
        }
    }

    public String getFullname () {
        try {
            return user.getString("fullname");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Calling the class

```
AsyncStorage as = new AsyncStorage(context);
as.getFullname()
```

Comment: Its not easy to get the react application context anywhere in the app. Can you help me how did you get the react application context?

Comment: @Tarun, oh I'm sorry but I'm not an expert so I would need to see what I did to help you with that. But since I moved on I'm working in another company and I don't have the original project.

Comment: @Tarun I have the same issue, were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with alarm clock in my application and I decided to use AsyncStorage on Android side, then I use the code below and I could get all values from AsyncStorage and generate all alarms that was registered in my application's AsyncStorage.

```
SQLiteDatabase readableDatabase = null;
        readableDatabase = ReactDatabaseSupplier.getInstance(this.reactContext).getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor catalystLocalStorage = readableDatabase.query("catalystLocalStorage", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        try {
            List<AlarmeDTO> listaAlarmes = new ArrayList<>();
            if (catalystLocalStorage.moveToFirst()) {

                do {
                    //Ex: key: 01082019_0800
                    //value: [{executionDate: 2019-08-01T08:00}]
                    String key = catalystLocalStorage.getString(0);
                    String json = catalystLocalStorage.getString(1);

                    if (dados.length == 3) {
                        ...generate my alarms with key and json
                    }

                } while (catalystLocalStorage.moveToNext());

            }//2_31082019_0900 - [{"idPrescricaoMedicamento":35,"nomeMedicamento":"VITAMINA"}]

        } finally {
            if (catalystLocalStorage != null) {
                catalystLocalStorage.close();
            }

            if (readableDatabase != null) {
                readableDatabase.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I had to make a slight adjustment because I was using this in MainActivity.java, instead of  `getInstance(this.reactContext)` I had to use `getInstance(getApplicationContext())`. Thanks this code helped a lot getting started.