# Storage which React native and native can access at the same time?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, storage

Is there a storage engine that is easily accessible from both React native and native ?

---

I have BottomNavigationView (in android) or TabBarViewController (in ios) implemented in native code.

I want to add badge when there are new unread items in each tab.

Data fetching is done in react-native side and it knows whether there's new data for each tab.

Now I want to store this data (whether each tab has new data for a user) somewhere so that native code can show badge for corresponding tabs (in BottomNavigationView or Tabbar)

Due to the complex setup of mixing React native and native, I think it'll be easier if there's storage that can be easily accessible from both world (RN and native)

Are there such storage engine?

Complex setup refers to:

Each tab has separate Activity(or ViewController) and each activity instantiates a new RN bundle.

In order to use BottomNavigationView with activity(not fragment), every activity has its own BottomNavigationView

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151030/how-to-read-asyncstorage-on-android-correctly